# multiple input into a Mapper in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to send two files to a hadoop reducer.
I tried DistributedCache, but anything I put using addCacheFile in main, doesn't seem to be given back to with getLocalCacheFiles in the mapper.

right now I am using FileSystem to read the file, but I am running locally so I am able to just send the name of the file. Wondering how to do this if I was running on a real hadoop system.

is there anyway to send values to the mapper except the file that it's reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a lot of problems with distribution cache, and sending parameters. Options worked for me are below:

For distributed cache usage:
For me it was a nightmare to get the url/path to file on HDFS in Map or Reduce, but with symlink it worked
in run() method of the job

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(file+"#rules.dat"), conf);
DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
```

and then read in Map or Reduce
in header, before methods

```
public static FileSystem hdfs;
```

and then in setup() method of Map or Reduce

```
hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).open(new Path ("rules.dat"));
```

For parameters:
Send some values to Map or Reduce (could be a filename to open from HDFS):

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    ...
    conf.set("level", otherArgs[2]); //sets variable level from command line, it could be a filename
    ...
}
```

then in Map or Reduce class just:

```
int level = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("level")); //this is int, but you can read also strings, etc.
```

Comment: hdfs I guess should be FSDataInputStream because you called open on the file. but I am still getting file not found though - I do feel I am a bit closer to figuring it out though. thanks

Comment: should new Configuration() be context.getConfiguration() ?

Comment: for hdfs yes you can try FSDataInputStream, also you can try to access like this hdfs://...

Comment: new Configuration() in the example above, is located in a main Class, not mapper, nor reducer, so there is no context yet, below it you put mapper and reducer classes, job name, etc.

Comment: Hadoop DistributedCache is now deprecated! I think now we change it to job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());

Answer (score 0):

If distributed cache suites your need - it is a way to go.

getLocalCacheFiles works differently in the local mode and in the distributed mode. (it actually do not work in local mode).

Look into this link: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html
look for the phrase: As a cautionary note: